# I'm having trouble installing perl module Crypt::OpenSSL::AES

Tags: encryption, perl, cpan

I'm having trouble installing a perl module onto my server called

Crypt::OpenSSL::AES

I'm using cpan to try to install it but it keeps coming back with an error:

```
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Crypt::OpenSSL::AES
cp lib/Crypt/OpenSSL/AES.pm blib/lib/Crypt/OpenSSL/AES.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/xsubpp -typemap /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap AES.xs > AES.xsc && mv AES.xsc AES.c
gcc -c -I. -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -DVERSION=\"0.02\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.02\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE" AES.c
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make: *** [AES.o] Error 127
TTAR/Crypt-OpenSSL-AES-0.02.tar.gz
make -- NOT OK
Running make test
Can't test without successful make
Running make install
Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

I have the crypt modules installed already:

Crypt::CBC

Crypt::Rijndael

but can't get Crypt::OpenSSL::AES installed. Any help would be much appreciated.
I'm using perl, v5.10.1 and Plesk Panel version 11.0.9 Update #63 
Thanks

Comment: Did you read through the error message? It's pretty clear what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is missing a C compiler. Install gcc and try again.